# undefined method Proxy for Proxifier:Module

Tags: ruby

I have a problem.

I installed subj:

```
gem install proxifier
```

then created socks.rb:

```
require "proxifier/proxy"

proxy = Proxifier::Proxy("socks://" + ARGV[0])
socket = proxy.open("www.google.com", 80)
socket << "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n"
socket.gets
```

and ran this script:

```
ruby socks.rb 127.0.0.1:1080
socks.rb:3:in `<main>': undefined method `Proxy' for Proxifier:Module (NoMethodE
rror)
```

Help plz.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **require "proxifier/proxy"**  use

**require "proxifier"**

Comment: I tried but<pre>    D:/tmp/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/proxifier-1.0.2/lib/proxifier/proxy.rb:26:i n open': undefined local variable or method proxy' for #<Proxifier::SOCKSProxy :0x1e40b00> (NameError) from socks.rb:4:in '<main>'</pre>